# Create empty array using reflection

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, instantiation

How do I create empty array of a type given by reflection? I have tried using the `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` method:

```
Type arrayType = typeof(string[]);
Activator.CreateInstance(arrayType);
```

but I get a `MissingMethodException` exception:

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Type arrayType = typeof(string[]); 
    Array.CreateInstance(arrayType, 5); 

or you could write 

    Type arrayType = typeof(System.Array);
    Array.CreateInstance(arrayType, 5)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Some types you have to trap and handle special, for your case you'd use:

```
if ( type.IsArray){
  var o = Array.CreateInstance(type, size);
}
```

Comment: This answer is clearly wrong.

Comment: Why is it? The misplaced curlies?

Comment: `Array.CreateInstance` takes the element type as first parameter, not the array type.

Comment: Ah.. ok. I'll adjust.

Comment: In fairness my code sample was coded like that type parameter was implied to mean the type of array element. I was not using the ops code.

Comment: I've corrected.

Comment: It's still wrong, you need to call `GetElementType()` on `type`. Right now `o` has type `System.Array[]` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Ha.. the point of the answer was to use CreateInstance  method and pass the type.  And declaring a var o on the ifv statement is also not correct.. I wasn't giving code to use. I was answering the question.

Comment: I'm on my phone.. and I'm not that interested

Comment: It's still wrong: it should be `var o = Array.CreateInstance(type.GetElementType(), size)`.

Comment: Excellent work! Congrats

Comment: But o is out of scope.